# Removing dense grid lines & convert into clear image - opencv - python

Tags: image-processing, python, opencv, text-recognition

I want to extract the text from this image. I'm a newbie in opencv. I've tried various opencv codes across various questions, but none is working for me.

How can I extract text from this? Or maybe remove grid lines & that circular bulge in the middle so that image is straightened & then I can extract the text.

Any help is appreciated.

One of the Sample codes I tried - [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/52089/removing-noisy-lines-from-image-opencv-python)

Another attempt is [this](https://Tried%20what%20you%20said.%20Can%20you%20help%20why%20this%20is%20not%20working%20-%20gist.github.com/pankajsinghal/5060eb7eb994e87ff0e118cf911fb18a) but this isn't working as well. Can someone advise what is wrong here? The basic algo followed is to fill in the pure blue and red lines. I tried to get them by thresholding them on the respective channels. Then tried to fill these pixels with an average of their immediate neighbours.

[image]